# Unity webview loading webpage locally/by storing cache

Tags: unity-game-engine, webview

I am trying to build a unity project, in my project i have to show the web page in app using unity webview either by loading locally or by once storing cache of that web page. i have tried loading locally by downloading a web page but without internet the content of the html files loaded but CSS, JS and Images are not. for loading locally i have pasted the folders and HTML file to a folder in project-> Assests-> Streaming Assets. Image for folders and HTML file is [Streaming Assets directory Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtDtk.png) the underlined folders and file is used. And in unity editor link for the file is provided like this:- [Unity Editor Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeeQz.png) and script used to load the file is below

```
case RuntimePlatform.OSXEditor:
    case RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer:
    case RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer:
    case RuntimePlatform.Android:
        if (Url.StartsWith("http")) {
            webViewObject.LoadURL(Url.Replace(" ", "%20"));
        } else {
            webViewObject.LoadURL("StreamingAssets/" + Url.Replace(" ", "%20"));
            var src = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, Url);
            var dst = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, Url);
            var result = "";
            if (src.Contains("://")) {
                var www = new WWW(src);
                yield return www;
                result = www.text;
            } else {
                result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(src);
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(dst, result);
            webViewObject.LoadURL("file://" + dst.Replace(" ", "%20"));
        }
        if (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.Android) {
            webViewObject.EvaluateJS(
                "window.addEventListener('load', function() {" +
                "   window.Unity = {" +
                "       call:function(msg) {" +
                "           var iframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');" +
                "           iframe.setAttribute('src', 'unity:' + msg);" +
                "           document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);" +
                "           iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);" +
                "           iframe = null;" +
                "       }" +
                "   }" +
                "}, false);");
        }
        break;
    #else
```

If anyone Knows Please help.